Kotlin compose, when doing collectAsState on a StateFlow how to perform an action after collection finishes
So lets imagine I'm collecting a state flow using collectAsState in my composable:
@Composable
internal fun Test(
    myViewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    val state by myViewModel.myStateFlow.collectAsState()
}

Now I want to perform an action when my composable is no longer collecting the state.
Note that this is simplified a lot. In the real example I can't use the disposal of the composable for that trigger. Essentially what I would like is something like this:
@Composable
internal fun Test(
    myViewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    val state by myViewModel.myStateFlow.collectAsState(onFinish: () {/*someaction*/})
}

I am really not sure how to implement this, so any help is appreciated.

Since the collection of a StateFlow will never stop on its own (it will never complete), what exactly will be the trigger? The only thing I can think of is a DisposableEffect that triggers when the composable leaves the composition.

You can copy the implementation of collectAsState, which is using produceState under the hood, and add the .onCompletion callback:
val state by produceState(
  initialValue = myViewModel.myStateFlow.value,
  key1 = myViewModel.myStateFlow
) {
  myViewModel.myStateFlow
    .onCompletion { /* Your action */ }
    .collect { value = it }
}


This won't work. Look at the documentation of StateFlow, it states in bold: "State flow never completes."

The stateflow doesn't complete, but the collection completes when you cancel the coroutine in which you are collecting. The onCompletion in this example will be called once the composable leaves composition and that's the desired behaviour afaik.

You are right, onCompletion also seem to on downstream cancellation not only upstream: "Unlike catch, this operator reports exception that occur both upstream and downstream". Didn't know that.

This works, but to give more detail, I have multiple state flows and I have a mutableStateOf variable which determines which stateflow should be used in the compose. So when changing the variable I change the stateflow and thus the state. Now Im wondering if this will be triggered on each variable change? Ill test and see

I guess it won't work like that. If you can add a better example of what you actually need to the original post, I can think about something.

It seems to be working. Ill add an example soon just so you can see in more details. Thank you
